# Why is my styled-a tag looks slightly upper in it's border?

Tags: css

I created  tag in the nav, and then style it but it looks like the text in the  tag is slightly upper in its own border. What should I need to do?

Comment: Where is the code???)

Answer (score 0):

**This is the code **

```css
.nav-button {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: blue;
    padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="nav-button">Contact</a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).